# Bar crossover wont work on my plotted box

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have coded to create a box when a specific confition is detected, the box is stored in an array and plot on the chart correctly.  I have plotted the box to cut off when price crosses the average line and all this plots ok however when i try and plot a label (or any other kind of alert) for when 'high' crosses the box line i cant get the lable to appear.  I've tried nesting the label inside the main conditoin 'if', and by itself.  I've also tried creating a separat array for box_lows and coding the crossover in general and whilst the code compiles Ok the condition never triggers the label even though i can see on the chart the condition should.  I've no idea why this is and would appreacite any help please
I just need to be able to get label to print once current_index high is greater htan box low, it seems so simple and yet just wont plot!  I'm sure the error must be something obvious but cannot work it out.

the full code is:-

```
//@version=5
indicator("My FVG Detector - Tester"
  , overlay = true
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Fair Value Gaps
show_fvg = input(true, 'Fair Value Gaps (FVG)'
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_fvg_css = input.color(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_fvg_css = input.color(#ff1100, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_usewidth = input(true, 'Min Width'
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_gapwidth = input.float(1.95, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_method = input.string('ATR', ''
  , options = ['Points', '%', 'ATR']
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_extend = input.int(3, 'Extend FVG'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_entry = input.int(80, 'Bull Entry Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_exit = input.int(80, 'Bull Exit Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

adboxcount = input.int (50, "Maximum Imb Displayed", 1, group = "Chart Customization")

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{


n = bar_index
atr = ta.atr(200)

//Detect imbalance and return count over time
imbalance_detection(show, usewidth, method, width, top, btm, condition, wide)=>
    var is_width = true
    var count = 0
    
    if usewidth
        dist = top - btm
        bull_wide = top - btm

        is_width := switch method
            'Points' => dist > width
            '%' => dist / btm * 100 > width
            'ATR' => dist > atr * width

    is_true = show and condition and is_width
    count += is_true ? 1 : 0
    
    [is_true, count]

    

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Arrays
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

var box[] imbboxarray = array.new_box()
var line[] bear_avg_line = array.new_line()
var float[] bear_boxlow = array.new_float()




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Fair Value Gaps
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Bullish
[bull_fvg, bull_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low
  , high[2]
  , low > high[2] and close[1] > high[2]
  , high[2] - low)
bull_top = bull_fvg
bull_width = high[2] - low
bull_avg = math.avg(low, high[2])

//Bearish
[bear_fvg, bear_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low[2]
  , high
  , high < low[2] and close[1] < low[2]
  , low[2] - high)
bear_top = bear_fvg
bear_width = low[2] - high
bear_avg = math.avg(low[2], high)
bearplot = high > low[1] ? 1 : 0


// Box & Line Calc {
f_choppedoffimb(imbboxarray, bear_avg_line) =>
    if array.size(imbboxarray) > 0 and array.size(bear_avg_line) > 0
        for i = array.size(imbboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
            cutbox = array.get(imbboxarray, i)
            cutline = array.get(bear_avg_line, i)
            boxhighzone = box.get_top(cutbox)
            boxlowzone = box.get_bottom(cutbox)
            boxrightzone = box.get_right(cutbox)
            bear_avg_right = line.get_x2(cutline)
            if na or bar_index - 1 == boxrightzone and not (high > boxhighzone)
                box.set_right(array.get(imbboxarray, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bear_avg_line, i), bar_index)

// }

// Box Draw {
if bear_top and bear_width > 0
    boxhighzone = bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? low[2] : low[0]
    boxlowzone = bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? high[0] : high[2]
    bear_box_low = low[1]
    bear_avg_right = bar_index
    imbbox = box.new(bar_index, boxhighzone, bar_index, boxlowzone, bear_fvg_css, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bear_fvg_css, 80))
    midline = line.new(bar_index, bear_avg, bear_avg_right, bear_avg, color = color.red, style = line.style_solid)
    if array.size(imbboxarray) > adboxcount
        box.delete(array.shift(imbboxarray))
        line.delete(array.shift(bear_avg_line))
    array.push(imbboxarray, imbbox)
    array.push(bear_avg_line, midline)
    array.push(bear_boxlow, low[1])

    if ta.crossover(high, boxlowzone)
        label.new(bar_index, bear_avg, "Bear", xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

f_choppedoffimb(imbboxarray, bear_avg_line)
// }
```

// Please help creating a label which is plotted each time a bar crosses the 'boxlowzone' or 'bear_box_low'.  I've tried every way i can think of and none of them plot. No idea why!

As above, I've tried nesting hte conditoin within the main 'if', calling the box values from arrays, setting the condition bool up globally and then trying to change it within the'if' (which is not allowed) and have now run out of ideas

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but it seems the labels are plotting anytmie the crossover occurs, but it shoul only occur with the range of the plotted box... could you help again please.  ive tried adding an 'if' before the labels but then nothing prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ta.crossover()` may not work reliably within `if`, better call it on each calculation.

In your script the crossover condition was not true at the times were you expected it to be true, since boxlowzone did not reflect the low border of the box, but was changing every bar.

(Left some debugging code inside, you may find that useful too)

Please check the script below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My FVG Detector - Tester"
  , overlay = true
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Fair Value Gaps
show_fvg = input(true, 'Fair Value Gaps (FVG)'
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_fvg_css = input.color(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_fvg_css = input.color(#ff1100, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_css'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_usewidth = input(true, 'Min Width'
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_gapwidth = input.float(1.95, ''
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_method = input.string('ATR', ''
  , options = ['Points', '%', 'ATR']
  , inline = 'fvg_width'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_extend = input.int(3, 'Extend FVG'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_entry = input.int(80, 'Bull Entry Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bull_exit = input.int(80, 'Bull Exit Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

adboxcount = input.int (50, "Maximum Imb Displayed", 1, group = "Chart Customization")

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{


n = bar_index
atr = ta.atr(200)

//Detect imbalance and return count over time
imbalance_detection(show, usewidth, method, width, top, btm, condition, wide)=>
    var is_width = true
    var count = 0
    
    if usewidth
        dist = top - btm
        bull_wide = top - btm

        is_width := switch method
            'Points' => dist > width
            '%' => dist / btm * 100 > width
            'ATR' => dist > atr * width

    is_true = show and condition and is_width
    count += is_true ? 1 : 0
    
    [is_true, count]

    

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Arrays
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{

var box[] imbboxarray = array.new_box()
var line[] bear_avg_line = array.new_line()
var float[] bear_boxlow = array.new_float()




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Fair Value Gaps
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Bullish
[bull_fvg, bull_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low
  , high[2]
  , low > high[2] and close[1] > high[2]
  , high[2] - low)
bull_top = bull_fvg
bull_width = high[2] - low
bull_avg = math.avg(low, high[2])

//Bearish
[bear_fvg, bear_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(
  show_fvg
  , fvg_usewidth
  , fvg_method
  , fvg_gapwidth
  , low[2]
  , high
  , high < low[2] and close[1] < low[2]
  , low[2] - high)
bear_top = bear_fvg
bear_width = low[2] - high
bear_avg = math.avg(low[2], high)
bearplot = high > low[1] ? 1 : 0


// Box & Line Calc {
f_choppedoffimb(imbboxarray, bear_avg_line) =>
    if array.size(imbboxarray) > 0 and array.size(bear_avg_line) > 0
        for i = array.size(imbboxarray) - 1 to 0 by 1
            cutbox = array.get(imbboxarray, i)
            cutline = array.get(bear_avg_line, i)
            boxhighzone = box.get_top(cutbox)
            boxlowzone = box.get_bottom(cutbox)
            boxrightzone = box.get_right(cutbox)
            bear_avg_right = line.get_x2(cutline)
            if na or bar_index - 1 == boxrightzone and not (high > boxhighzone)
                box.set_right(array.get(imbboxarray, i), bar_index)
                line.set_x2(array.get(bear_avg_line, i), bar_index)

// }

var boxhighzone = 0.
var boxlowzone = 0.

boxhighzone := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? low[2] : boxhighzone
boxlowzone := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? high[0] : boxlowzone
bear_box_low = low[1]
bear_avg_right = bar_index
var belowBoxhighzone = false
if imbboxarray.size() > 0
    belowBoxhighzone := (high > box.get_top(imbboxarray.last())) ? false : belowBoxhighzone

crossoverHighBoxLowZone =  ta.crossover(high, boxlowzone) and belowBoxhighzone


if crossoverHighBoxLowZone
    label.new(bar_index, bear_avg, "Bear", xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

// Box Draw {
if bear_top and bear_width > 0
    imbbox = box.new(bar_index, boxhighzone, bar_index, boxlowzone, bear_fvg_css, border_style = line.style_dashed, bgcolor = color.new(bear_fvg_css, 80))
    midline = line.new(bar_index, bear_avg, bear_avg_right, bear_avg, color = color.red, style = line.style_solid)
    if array.size(imbboxarray) > adboxcount
        box.delete(array.shift(imbboxarray))
        line.delete(array.shift(bear_avg_line))
    array.push(imbboxarray, imbbox)
    array.push(bear_avg_line, midline)
    array.push(bear_boxlow, low[1])
    belowBoxhighzone := true


bgcolor(bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? color.rgb(255, 235, 59, 57) : na)
bgcolor(crossoverHighBoxLowZone ? color.rgb(213, 59, 255, 56) : na)

plotchar(bear_top, "bear_top", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(bear_width, "bear_width", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(boxlowzone, "boxlowzone", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(crossoverHighBoxLowZone, "crossoverHighBoxLowZone", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(array.size(label.all), "label.all.size()", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(array.size(box.all), "box.all.size()", "", location = location.top)


// if bar_index % 20 == 0  
//     label.new(bar_index, bear_avg, "Bear", xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)

f_choppedoffimb(imbboxarray, bear_avg_line)
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of *boxhighzone* changes on each candle.
for `ta.crossover`, it must be a fixed line

Try this:

```
boxHigh = 0.0
boxHigh := bear_top and bear_width > 0 ? low[2] : nz(boxHigh[1])
if ta.crossover(high, boxHigh)
    label.new(bar_index, bear_avg, "Bear", xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
```